unencryted rsyslog through wireguard tunnel
We have a server and two cients with wireguard on them.  The server is 10.10.10.1, the first
client is 10.10.10.2 and the second client is 10.10.10.3.  The tunnel works and I can
ping from server -> client and vice versa.
I now want to send logs from both clients to the server.  The server then forwards all logs
to another server.  For the rsyslog portion, I do not need or want data traversing the tunnel to be
encrypted.  As of now I cannot get an established TCP connection from either client to the server.  Here are my configs - what am I doing wrong?
Server:
global(defaultNetStreamDriver="ptcp") - I've tried both with and without this line

$ModLoad imtcp

$InputTCPServerStreamDriverAuthMode anon
$InputTCPServerStreamDriverMode 0
$InputTCPServerRun 6514

$template LDSTag, "<%PRI>%TIMESTAMP [nameofsystem] %syslog% %msg%"

# 10.50.x.x is where the server sends its data via udp
if $fromhost-ip <> '127.0.0.1' then @10.50.x.x;LDSTag 
&stop
auth.*;authpriv.*;cron.*;daemon.*;kern.*;local0.*;local4.* @10.50.x.x;LDSTag

Here is my client setup:
global(defaultNetStreamDriver="ptcp") - I've tried both with and without this line

$ModLoad imtcp

$template LDSTag,"<%PRI>%TIMESTAMP [PUBLIC_IP] %syslog% %msg%"

#Send Settings
$ActionWriteAllMarkMessages on
$ActionSendStreamDriverPermittedPeer "10.0.0.1"
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 0

auth.*;authpriv.*;cron.*;daemon.*;kern.*;local0.*;local4.* @@10.10.10.10.1:6514;LDSTmpl

